# Construct a tree from edges

Tags: java, algorithm, graph, tree

If I'm trying to construct a tree given input with one edge per line, where an edge is represented by the two vertices it connects. Is it possible to construct a tree using a Node struct/class or should I just represent it as an adjacency list like I would a graph?

The main problem I'm having is the order of the input. If I'm given two or more edges that are not at all connected at first, then I have a bunch of Node objects with no connection whereas normally you're given a tree and inserting into a tree is simply making the new node a child (or parent?) of another node.

Comment: To the question you ask: it seems like you can detect the nodes from the edges, no?  I mean, if the edge identifies two vertices, wouldn't the edges be vertices?

Comment: Don't understand this "If I'm given two or more edges that are not at all connected at first". Are edges supposed to be connected? Anyway if you'll know the number of vertices in advance, you should you an adjacency list. It's simple and memory efficient.

Comment: To the question you don't ask: you'll need to detect whether you've already identified the nodes.  I'm not an expert on graphing, but you'll need to consider how you're maintaining your map.  If it's simply a bunch of nodes that link to each other, can you maintain a second structure, like a bucket tree, that will allow you to quickly identify if you have already recorded a node?

Comment: @atk: I can know the vertices from the edges but I don't know how to store the vertices in intermediate steps.

Comment: @Duc: I mean if an edge from one part of the tree is given after an edge from a different part of the tree. They will be two edges and four vertices. How would I store this? I normally just have one root node. I will want to traverse the tree later in the common way (inorder/preorder etc.) and that requires having access to some root node so I want to store it similarly to how I normally would but how do I connect the unconnected nodes?

Comment: In that case, please see if my answer below will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you worry about how to store many nodes instead of one root node, one way is to have an array of N pointers to Node. Assume each node is indexed 0 to N - 1 where N is the number of nodes in the tree, you can store the i-th Node pointer in the i-th element of the array.

This approach is even more beneficial if instead of using pointer, you'll allocate the array of N nodes at once in the stack (in C/C++). That is a huge improvement in memory allocation time.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered utilizing graph database technology such as neo4j to store your nodes and edges? It's embeddable.

I've used embedded orientdb with tinkerpop blueprints on scala extensively for graphing algorithms. I would recommend you check out these technologies as they make these problems and graph algorithm construction trivial.

Property graph dbs use indices to allow lookup of type so you can find a node and start traversing the graph from there. No need to re-invent the wheel.

The major concepts are: a node, an edge, a property (which can exist on either a node or an edge. an edge type ('knows' for example in a social graph). An out and an in side for determining traversal direction of the edges. And the indices as mentioned which 'type' the nodes and allow lookup.

Each node can be queried for in or out edges and edge types and properties can be examined.